# How would I find get the distinct digits of a number Python

Tags: python, numbers, digits

I need to find all the distinct digits of a number and put them in an array, without looping.

I have already tried looping, but it is too slow.

If the number was 4884, then I would get [4,8] as an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> r = set(map(int, str(4884))) 
>>> r
{8, 4}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without set?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy `unique`:

```
num = 4884
res = np.unique(list(str(num))).astype(int)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[4 8]
```

---

You can also do something like this:

```
list(dict(zip(map(int, list(str(num))), [0]*len(str(num)))).keys())
```

Not sure why you would want something so complicated. It is probably not faster than using `set`.

---

Some tests:

```
import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('import numpy as np; np.unique(list(str(4884))).astype(int)', number=10000)
0.1892512352597464
timeit.timeit('set(map(int, str(4884)))', number=10000)
0.02349709570256664
timeit.timeit('map(int, list(dict.fromkeys(list(str(4884)))))', number=10000)
0.02554667675917699
timeit.timeit('list(dict(zip(map(int, list(str(4884))), [0]*len(str(4884)))).keys())', number=10000)
0.03316584026305236
```

Using `set` is definitely the fastest.

Comment: I cant use numpy

Comment: You can't use numpy. You don't want to use set. You should mention all of these constraints in the question.

Comment: @MathWiz I think you have all the reasonable options here.

Comment: If set is the fastest method, then I will use it. My question is, is there a faster way?

Comment: @MathWiz see some speed tests. I doubt you'll find faster than using `set`

Answer (score 0):

use this technique

```
a = 658556
a = str(a)
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(list(a)))
print(mylist)
```

output:

```
['6', '5', '8']
```

Comment: Just map your final result to int